# How create GeoIP functionality in PHP project?

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip

I have some IP adress (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) and I must receive (learn) name of country and it would be nice if I can receive (learn) name of city too. And don't forget It's php-project, useful API - very good.

**P.S.** It's some open-source project and we must use only free and open-source tools.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 5):

None (only the 'GeoIP.dat' file is needed).  To download a free GeoIP Standard Country
database, go to
http://maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/

Install

Just place the 'geoip.inc' file somewhere according to the 'include_path' directive of
your 'php.ini' file, or just place it in the same directory as your PHP scripts.

Usage

Gets country name by hostname :

```
include("geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\n";
echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\n";
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a ton, +1. But note you have to `geoip_close()` and that you'll need the other databases for gathering things like city names and ASNs (their ISPs) and IPv6 support requires the databases suffixed by "v6".

Comment: This should be best answer . free services like `ipinfo.io` are not reliable  I always I got error message and some time they ban may IP address . Last they use same DB this from their site "This product includes GeoLite2 data "

Answer (score 2):

PHP has some useful builtin [GeoIP-functions](http://php.net/geoip). They should be sufficient:

```
$details = geoip_record_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $details['city'];
```

Comment: It's not because they're in the manual that they're built-in, you know... This one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

**In Linux Environment**
 1. sudo yum install php56-devel geoip geoip-devel php-pear
 2. sudo pecl install geoip
 3. extension=geoip.so  (add this line in php.ini)
 4. move .dat file in /usr/share/GeoIP folder

**In Windows Environment**
 1. move .dll in ext folder
 2. move .dat file in apache/bin folder
 3. add dll extension in php.ini