# Fetching the current country name using ip address in php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a dropdown in which i fetch country name from database and i want to select current country name based on there ip address in dropdown box

Comment: let me get this straight, what are the options in the dropdown? IPs?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422817/how-create-geoip-functionality-in-php-project

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and write clear posts. Thus helping others help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741347/how-to-get-country-code-and-currency-code-by-ip-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP GeoIP API](http://php.net/geoip). NOTE: you need to setup the [Maxmind GeoIP API database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) before you can use the functions.

```
<select name="securityqustion"  class="securityqustion" id="security_qustion">
<?php
  // will resolve 2-character ISO country code
  $request_country = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);  

  $countries = array("DE" => "Germany", "FR" => "France", ...);  // define list
  foreach ($countries as $country_code => $country_label) {
    if ($request_country == $country_code) 
      $selected = "selected"
    else 
      $selected = "";
    echo "<option value=\"{$country_code}\" {$selected}>{$country_label}</option>\n";
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[MaxMind GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) has a free API for PHP for finding someone's country based on their IP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an IP Geolocation web service. Most of them are paid, but they provide some (usually limited) free access as well.

I have used http://www.maxmind.com/ and http://ipinfodb.com/ successfully in the past and a friend has good things to say about http://www.geoplugin.com/

Answer (score -2):

system('traceroute ' . $trace_ip_addr); // Trace IP address.

Comment: First install traceroute in the system

Comment: sudo apt-get install traceroute